# Copy Email Body to EventItem or Appointmentitem Body 1:1

Tags: vba, outlook

I keep running into a issue and after multiple days trying to work around it, I am now at a stand still and am really hoping someone here can point me to a solution.

I am creating a VB program that takes a user's input and creates a standardardized email auto filled with the given information and the correct receivers of that information (Using Outlook 2016).  The Program is suppose to also create a appointmentitem or eventitem and copy over the body of the email directly over to the event/appointmentitem 1:1.

The email body unfortunately has a table in it that also needs to be copied over.  Everything I read online says that event/appointmentitems will only take RTF text and that is why I am having so much issue correctly moving the table from the email to the event, however, my question is why can I right click in the email copy the entire body and paste it without issue within the event and the table looks 100 percent correct and yet I can't somehow program in VB the same motions to create a good copy?

I have tried:
Getting input in RTF format instead of HTML, finding a useable HTML to RTF function, and tried using the Clipboard.

TLDR: I can simply copy a email body (with included table) and paste it 1:1 in outlook event item and yet I can't do the same process using VB code, am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe add the (imperfect) code you have so far, so that others don't have to recreate it from scratch...

Answer (score 1):

I think your best best might be to use the Word object model, pulling the Word document for both the mail item and event item. Then, you can paste the mail item into the event item. Something like this:

```
  Public Sub TransferEmailToEvent()
     Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem, oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem

     ' using late binding, so your users won't have to add a reference
     ' to Word in their Outlook instance to be able to run this
     Dim wdMailDoc As Object, wdEventDoc As Object

     Set oMsg = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
     oMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

     ' of course, here you'd insert the HTML into the email however you do now.
     oMsg.HTMLBody = "<table border=""1""><trow><td>Apple</td><td>Banana</td></trow></table>"

     ' you have to display the mail item before you can get its inspector
     oMsg.Display

     Set wdMailDoc = oMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor
     wdMailDoc.Range.Copy

     Set oAppt = Outlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
     Set wdEventDoc = oAppt.GetInspector.WordEditor

     ' 1 = wdPasteRTF
     wdEventDoc.Range.PasteSpecial datatype:=1

     oAppt.Display
  End Sub
```