# Copy Email body (HTML formatted) into AppointmentItem

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office365, vsto, outlook-addin

I wrote a VSTO add-in for Outlook. I am in a Microsoft Exchange environment at my company and we use Office 365.
In a function of the add-in I want to copy the complete content of an email (HTML formatted), which also contains a table, into the body of the AppointmentItem.
I followed the recommendation in this post [Copy Email Body to EventItem or Appointmentitem Body 1:1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270644/) and used the Word object model for that.

Here is my code:

```
    Sub CopyHtmlBodyfromMailToAppointment(CurrentMail As MailItem, CurrenAppointment As AppointmentItem)

            CurrenAppointment.Display()  ' has to be displayed, in order to make copy and past work!
            CurrentMail.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
            CurrenAppointment.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
            Dim objWordDocumentMail As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = CurrentMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

            objWordDocumentMail.Range.Copy()

            Dim objWordDocumentAppointment As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = CurrenAppointment.GetInspector.WordEditor
            Call objWordDocumentAppointment.Range.PasteSpecial(DataType:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML)
    End Sub
```

My problem is, that **sometimes the complete email content is not copied**. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. For example, if I call the function 5 times in a row with the same email as the source, it worked perfectly 2 times and 3 times the content is not copied until the end of the email.
The beginning is always there, but it is then cut off anywhere in the middle.

I was able to determine that the problem is already with the
`objWordDocumentMail.Range.Copy()` command. If I set a breakpoint after the command and then paste the contents of the clipboard into Word, I see that the entire body isn't copied.
My suspicion is that the range object doesn't necessarily encompass the entire body of the email.
I tested with range specifications, e.g. Range(0,200). This fixed number of characters is then always copied.
If I specify a length greater than the email body, I get an error message. Since I don't know the exact length of the email body, I can't get any further at this point.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can always reliably transfer the entire email body to an appointment body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using the `Range` method you can try calling the [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.select) method which selects the contents of the specified document, so you can be sure all the content will be included in the copy operation.

Also you may consider setting the `PR_HTML` property directly using a low-level code (`Extended MAPI` or any other wrapper around this API can be used, for example, `Redemption`) to a byte array (binary representation of the HTML body). The store provider should automatically convert HTML to RTF when the item is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene's recommendation solved my problem. Before using the `Range` method, I use the `Select` method on the Word document.

```
objWordDocumentMail.Select()
objWordDocumentMail.Range().Copy()
```

From then on, the complete email content were transferred to the appointment object.

Many thanks to Eugene, great support!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
It is generally considered sufficient to upvote or accept an answer to express appreciation, and a seperate "Thank you" message is not necessary. 

I hope you find this information useful for future use. 

Alon Alush